# How to redirect all pages in a subfolder to a single page

Tags: redirect

I recently changed my site's directory structure and also started using php to generate file names. All of my previous files have been renamed so that they can be easily accessed via the mysql/php. Site works fine.  Problem is existing links on external sites point to the old directory/file, e.g.,

```
<site>/library_wheels/wheel-1-name.html
<site>/library_wheels/wheel-2-name.html
<site>/library_wheels/wheel-3-name.html
```

I want any request to any html file in the old library_wheels directory (which no longer exists) to go to a general index page:

```
 <site>/library_wheels.php.
```

There the visitor can look up the right link.

Or should I put in nearly a thousand 301 redirects in the .htacess file?

Thanks

Mar 22: tried @Marc B's answer; doesn't work.

June 14, 2015: tisantisan's answer worked, but I had to specify the full url of the destination page:
    RewriteRule ^http://www.bps.lk/library_wheels.php [R=301,L,NC]

Or else, @Marc B's answer worked, but I must have typed it in wrong!

Comment: `rewriterule ^<site>/library_wheels /library_wheels.php`, basically

Comment: I have tried
    RewriteRule ^/library_wheels /library_wheels.php

Comment: @Marc B
I have tried
    RewriteRule ^/library_wheels /library_wheels.php
    RewriteRule ^bps.lk/library_wheels /library_wheels.php
    RewriteRule ^/library_wheels/* /library_wheels.php
    RewriteRule ^library_wheels/ /library_wheels.php
and nothing works.

Comment: @Bhante-S *don't* update your question with things like "solved", instead, mark an answer as accepted or if there is no answer that truly matches the solution, make a new answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^library_wheels/ library_wheels.php [R=301,L,NC]
```

Comment: I should have explained a bit here: 
The first part "
Options +FollowSymLinks 
RewriteEngine On
"
 goes at the beginning of your .htaccess file. You probably already have it. If not, do so.
Then, the RewriteRule given previously doesn't say the kind of redirection (301 or permanent in your case) so:
"
RewriteRule ^library_wheels/ library_wheels.php [R=301,L,NC]
"
should be enough